# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/mailcap.default'

Tags: android

I try to send mail by Gmail but it create an error.When i build my app, I got no error but when i run my app then it gives following error

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/mailcap.default'

I try many things but it not solve so please help.
Thanks

My app build.gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.mysqldatabaseapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {

    pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
}


dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is more than one of your dependencies that including `META-INF/mailcap.default` inside their package. So, you need to use only one of `META-INF/mailcap.default` by adding the `pickFirst` line. Something like this:

```
packagingOptions {
    // use only one
    pickFirst 'META-INF/mailcap.default'

    pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```